# ionic build android : Overwrite all code

Tags: ionic-framework

When I build ionic app using this command

> ionic build android

Then my code overwrite with default code..What i have to do my code remain as it is and i can build app. Help me to solve this problem
I created ionic using following code

```
 ionic start myapp blank
```

Please help to solve this

I am using ubantu os
How can i solve this problem and build successfully and my code remain as it is
I am building rest api example. I used below code

```
.controller('RegistrationCtrl', function($scope,$http, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.login = function() {
            alert("hi");
            $http
            (
            {method:"POST",url:"http://XXXX:8080/TestApp/addAcc/",
            params:{"email_address": $scope.data.email,"Code":{"password":$scope.data.password}},header:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}}
            ).success(function(data) {


                 alert("succ");
           }).error(function(data) {
               var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                   title: 'Login failed!',
                   template: 'Please check your credentials!'
               });

                       });
       }
})
```

Comment: If simon's answer didn't help you please edit your question in what you want to achive ?, do you want to make code same after you build android ?, where do you write the code ? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with *overwrite*? 
Only code inside the platform directory will be overwritten with a build.
Are you sure, that you don't change files inside `platforms/android/...`

I think that is the problem. Depending on your development tool you have to care about. Because if you search files by name or something like that. It happens to me sometimes, but then I add a filter to the search routine in my IDE(IntelliJ)